# How can we say "I see my dreams not happening"

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

I want to say that **I can see my dreams falling apart**. Is it correct?

I mean to say that the things I want to do (or happen) in the future seem to be impossible.. How can I say it?

Comment: I see my dreams *crumbling* (with the possible addition: *before my very eyes*).

Comment: "Dream is collapsing" *- a [soundtrack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imamcajBEJs) by Hans Zimmer for Inception*. Also, my favourite musician.

Comment: ... or 'I can see my dreams disappearing [...]'.

Comment: "I see my dreams floating/drifting away"

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry to hear that..
Your dreams are **broken** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/broken+dreams)

> Wishes or desires that cannot be fulfilled.
>   *"We all have our share of broken dreams, but they were never all meant to come true anyway."*

Your dreams are **shattered** — [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shattered)

> To cause the destruction or ruin of; destroy
>   *"The outcome of the conflict shattered our dreams of peace and prosperity."*

Your dreams are **far fetched** — [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/far-fetched)

> improbable; not naturally pertinent; being only remotely connected; forced; strained:

Your dreams have **gone out the window** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+out+the+window)

> If a quality, principle, or idea goes out of the window, it does not exist any more.
>   *"Then people start drinking and sense goes out of the window."*

You only have **pipe dreams** — [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pipe+dream)

> A fanciful or impossible plan or hope

Answer (score 0):

*I see my dreams [**going up in smoke**](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22dreams+going+up+in+smoke%22&biw=658&bih=431&prmd=ivn&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6teb_lZPMAhUG2RoKHRhkAEkQ_AUICygG&dpr=2)*

> go up in smoke *or* end (up) in smoke
>
> : to come to nothing
>
> [Collins English Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/go-up-in-smoke)
>
> [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dreams+going+up+in+smoke&year_start=1970&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdreams%20going%20up%20in%20smoke%3B%2Cc0)

*I see my dreams **fading away** [into nothing]/[**vanishing**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dreams+going+up+in+smoke%2Cdreams+vanishing%2Cdreams+fading+away&year_start=1970&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdreams%20going%20up%20in%20smoke%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdreams%20vanishing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdreams%20fading%20away%3B%2Cc0)*

> fade away
>
> To dissipate or fade slowly and completely.
>
> [The American Heritage® Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fade+away)

Answer (score 0):

Langston Hughes suggests several possible outcomes for deferred/unfulfilled dreams in the following poem:

> [Harlem](http://genius.com/Langston-hughes-harlem-what-happens-to-a-dream-deferred-annotated)
>
> What happens to a dream deferred?
>   Does it **dry up**
>    Like a raisin in the
>   sun?
>   Or fester like a sore--
>   And then run?
>    Does it stink like rotten
>   meat?
>   Or crust and sugar over--
>   like a syrupy sweet?
>   Maybe it just sags
>   like a heavy load.
>   Or does it explode?

(from ‘Genius[dot]com’)

I think Mr. Hughes’ first suggestion (or variation thereof) would work in your example sentence:

“I can see my dreams drying up/([shriveling up](http://figment.com/books/34604-Shriveled-Up-Leaves-Shriveled-Up-Dreams)).”

(example of “shriveled up” describing dreams in the title of a work by Kathryn-Bug, via ‘figment[dot]com' )